# Getting Null pointer exception while loading properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, properties, properties-file

I am trying to load the properties file in maven project(IntelliJ IDE).
While loading i am facing null pointer exception.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at main.com.bby.dao.EventListDao.getEventList(EventListDao.java:29)
    at main.com.bby.controller.EventController.allEventLists(EventController.java:39)
    at main.com.bby.controller.EventController.getAllEventLists(EventController.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Below is the piece of code**

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream propFile = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
        prop.load(propFile);
        System.out.println("Properties file loaded!!");
        propFile.close();
```

**Folder Structure of the project**

[image]

Below is the result of **classloader**:

```
ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: Dashboard
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@675d3402
```

I did search on almost every page for the fix but still not luck. That is why i had to post it as new question.
Kindly excuse if any grammatical error.
And thank you for the help.

Comment: your properties file should be in a resources folderµ

Comment: Did you check propFile object? I think it's coming as null. In that case, your db.properties file isn;t found.

Comment: Learn to debug. try the below to know if the NPE is due to path not being found or something else `File file = new File("db.properties");
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `db.properties` file in the `src/main/resources` folder and then you should be able to access it

Comment: I have verified this on my PC and it works, hope it works for OP also.

Comment: Thank you.It is working now. Added my properties under src/main/resources folder

Answer (score 0):

Create the following structure first:

src/main/java/%all your packages and classes here%
src/main/resources/%put everything that is not java code here%

Then, right click on the resources folder and mark it as Resources Root, do the same for the java folder but instead mark it as Sources Root.

Build the project and you should be able to load db.properties using

```
System.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/db.properties");
```

Hope this helps. If you encounter further issues feel free to comment down below.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

test.properties is saved in src/main/resources

test.properties:

```
com.test.name=JohnDoe
```

Application.java:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try(InputStream is = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties")) {
            properties.load(is);
        }

        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("com.test.name"));
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
JohnDoe

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

IDE follows Maven rules here. Since Maven by default will not copy resources which are not in `src/main/resources` folder. You should either copy them to this folder or configure maven to include them on compile by, for example:

```
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.vm</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```